# How to remove a white polygon that is fading into a complex background in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

In this picture, showing the bottom left part of door (please ignore the black area), I need to remove the white shape. I am attaching the picture before, and the picture after. 
The picture after is my attempt at removing the white shape, but the quality is not good at all. The colors aren't right, the door frame fades into a blur, and in general I've added way too much blur to try and hide the problems.

I have used patch and healing tools, various brushes in lighten / darken mode, etc...

What would be the right way to remove this white shape ?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make a spare copy of your layer that has the defect
- select the area to be fixed by a lasso, path or otherwise
- invert the selection
- save the selection to be able to restart from here
- take Edit > Puppet warp; see how the good area is divided by a network
- insert handles on the node points by clicking; at first click a solid line of nodes far from the bad area to prevent any deformations here
- Select nodes on the border of the bad area and stretch the good area over the bad by dragging the border nodes
- move also a bunch of intermediate nodes to prevent the texture overstrething
- heal off the maybe visible sharp edge of the stretched area.

Alternatively you can try cloning or even painting. It is very slow way because of the needed amout of care

A semiautomatic alternative is to try to fix the unsharpness in limited area by Smart Sharpen. There are even 3rd party tools for refocusing without other sharp photos of same or nearly same area.

Thatlike processing needs a photo where original mathematically linear camera raw data is only minimally or not at all noise reduced and processed for good visual exposure, contrast, sharpness and colors. JPGs outputted from modern camera are maybe "no hope" cases.